# Angular2 CanActivate Navigate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have following problem. I have made a CanActivate Guard where if you are logged in you can "go" to Debts Component. My problem is when I am logged in and i want to redirect User to Debts Component ( because RegistrationComponent is default ), but it's not working ( actually my page is blocking.. And i cannot do anything ). My CanActivate function

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

constructor(private router: Router) { }

canActivate(): Promise<boolean>{
    return checkIfAuth().then(() => {
        setLoggedIn(true);
        this.router.navigate(['/debts']); // <- broken :(
        return true;
    }).catch(() => {
        setLoggedIn(false);
        this.router.navigate(['/login']); // <- broken :(
        return false;
    })
  }
}


export function checkIfAuth () {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if(user){
            return resolve(true);
        }
        else{
            return reject(false);
        }
    })
  })
}
```

any my app.routing

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/registration', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {  path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'myaccount', component: AccountComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
    { path: 'debts', component: DebtsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]}
];
```

Comment: There is something I don't understand in your post. What is the exact problem ? You want the user to go to `DebtsComponent` if he is already logged In ? How do you reach the `LoginComponent` ?

Comment: I reach the loginComponent from Menu :) 
When i am logged in it looks like ( Debts Account SingOut ) and when not ( Registration Log In ). 
My problem is : I want to redirect User ALWAYS ( when he is logged ) to DebtsComponent ( when he wants to reach Login/Registration Component ) and redirect USER ALWAYS ( when he is not logged in ) to LoginComponent ( when he wants to reach Debts/Account Component ).

Comment: We might need the code when you login, but my hint would be that on `Login`, you should try to navigate to your Debts component, and in your guard only return `true` if the user is loggedIn (and not navigate in your guard).

Comment: Yes, yes i did it and it works ( it's not a problem :D ). Look, after you are logged in, you are redirected to localhost/debts and it's ok, but USER can change the URL by himself ( localhost/login ) and i want to redirect him, when he is logged ( because you cannot login when you are already logged :P ). Do you know what am i talking about? :(

Comment: Oh alright. I get it now.

Comment: Can i make two AuthGuards? ( ofc with different class name ) Or Should I just use one?

Comment: You can make several guards, but in your case I think only one would be enough. Check out my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did was kind of a hack but it works flawlessly :

First, I did setup a `Guard` on my `LoginCompoment` route.

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```

And then I use the `RouterStateSnapshot` to get a single instance of my URL state, indicating me what the user tried to reach.

I can then manage the cases in the Guard :

```js
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

...

/**
 *  Protects the routes to reach with authentication
 */
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    // Set user authentication state depending on the token's existance
    this.authService.setLoggedInState();
    // Check user authentication state
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated) {
        // Explicit navigation to '/login' while the user is already authenticated
        if (state.url === '/login') {
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']); // Debts for you
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        // Allow route to './login' to get authenticated
        if (state.url === '/login') {
            return true;
        }
        // Explicit navigation to any URL while not being authenticated
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Documentation link about Snapshots : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#sts=Snapshot:%20the%20no-observable%20alternative

To make it work in your case, you just have to adapt the `setLoggedInState()` to your case which it seems you already have.

**N.B :** I call this solution a **HACK** because you actually set a guard on the `Login` while it will still allow the user to reach it even if he is not authenticated. Still works well tho.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Actually had to "change" a little bit this code, but works very good! Thanks :)

Comment: No problem ! Glad I could help :)

Comment: @AlexBeugnet I would not call it a hack though, everything looks legitimate to me. How your Guard behaves is completely up to you. Generally speaking, basing your Guard's decision on the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` also allows you to recycle a single Guard for different routes instead of creating several individual Guards for different routes.